# Get last version not working Visual Studio 2012 in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have Visual Studio 2012 and when I'm trying to get last version it doesn't work and it says that it's says that "All files are up to date". It is because I deleted file locally after I got it from TFS and I guess in Visual Studios memory it's written that there were no changes from that time I got it and now it doesn't let me download it although I don't have it.

How to "tell" VS that my local folder is changed?

P.S. I guess it can be also done with "Get specific version" but that option doesn't appear to me when i right-click on file I want to get from server.

EDIT:

I found that my workspace changed automatically (or rather with me not being concentrated while making new project), so VS was actually checking other directory all the time. For all those who might have the same problem - check your local path and if you see that it's not good, change it. 
Here is how you can change it:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/d0c6982f-4f5e-4b1c-830b-3af9fb127922/

Comment: Can you do Undo pending changes and then Get Latest.

Comment: As an aside: if you don't like having to do absolutely everything through Visual Studio, you might want to give [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) a try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, TFS saves what version he gaves you and changing/deleting it without to notify TFS, you won't get anything. The "Get Specific Version ..." is what you need. Therefore rightclick on the item you want, in context menu choose "Advanced --> Get Specific Version". Check the second option to "Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version".

Comment: I did that exactly (thanks for telling me whee get specific version is) and it was processing and I was thinking that it should be present locally, but it's still not. What's wrong with this?

Comment: OK, I've found what was the problem - somehow path was changed, and it went to my c:\documents instead of where it was. I'll try to change it. Thanks for helping, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not saying this is a solution, but I had similar issues after remapping one of my projects. Ultimately what I did was delete my local Solution File (.sln) and re-opened the project via the Project File (.vbproj). After that I was able to see all of my latest file versions that appeared to not be down loading. Once you click save on anything it will re-prompt you to save a new solution file.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if this is specifically what the OP was trying to accomplish, but here's my story: my machine crashed, had to get it reimaged; once VS2015 was installed,  i  went to source control explorer, right clicked the branch i needed >> Advanced >> Get Specific Version, checked the "Overwrite..." boxes, clicked "Get" and got the "All files up to date..." message. buster. obviously the code was NOT up to date.

fast forward: i fixed this issue by deleting my workspace's pertinent mapping to code base i needed, saved it, and re-added it.

hope this saves some headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to Get Specific Version and to check the box to enable overwriting of existing files. That will ensure you're actually up to date.

You can also switch from a server worspace to the new local workspace which should also help solve issues like this.